# How can I send data SQLite (offline) to server MySQL using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

When there is no signal I use offline mode by storing data to the device (SQLite). After there is a signal I try to send the data to the Mysql server.

How can I send data from SQLite (offline mode) to MySQL server?

Comment: Are you using any webserver in the middle of your app and the database ? usually its done that way, your app sends / gets the requests from server, so wen offline just cache it to sqllite after get online just send it all to the server that will persist to the mysql database.

Comment: Ok i ll try.. many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a DB similar to your sqflite db's table in a remote server. then, create a rest api using your desired language(php is easy to start). then, when the app is connected to internet, use HTTP client to send the data to the remote server.

you can use a code like below for the post data call:

```
Future<dynamic> post(String url, {Map headers, body, encoding}) {
print(url);
print(body);
return http
    .post(BASE_URL+url, body: body, headers: headers, encoding: encoding)
    .then((http.Response response) {
  final String res = response.body;
  final int statusCode = response.statusCode;

  print(res);

  if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
    throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
  }
  return _decoder.convert(res);
});
}
```

Comment: Is rest api like when we insert data to mysql server?

Comment: nope a rest api is just a url link accomplish the format of its specification, that maps the post request to the method in an application running at the server, that will insert your posted data to mysql server.

Comment: Basically its the same thing that I've told you in my previous comment :)

Comment: @DwiNurRohman, as Diago Garcia explained, rest api is a medium by which you send data to server, and the data gets inserted to mysql. you cant actually insert data any mysql database, from android. you need a medium for that. theres lots of example in the internet. check please. here is a [link[(https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html)

Comment: @diegogarcia and Starlut

Comment: Sorry offline for some day..I mean whether the rest api that is used is the same as the rest api when we will insert data with 1 row of data, whereas when using sqflite there are several rows of data want to insert

Comment: what do you mean by 1row of data? did you mean column?

Comment: no, I mean 1 row of data like we will enter data into the table

Comment: Sorry my bad. Kind of the same. You send a list of object to bring entered in db. Same is done in rest API. @Dwi Nur Rohman

Comment: Rest API is basically your dbhelper class for server

Comment: no problem :) if i solved your problem, dont forget to accept the answer :P :)