# Sync SQFLite database with MySQL in Flutter?

Tags: mysql, database, flutter, synchronization, sqflite

I have a feedback app and I want to save some data for offline use in flutter app.
I want to save data temporarily (if the internet is not available) then SYNC to MySQL.
I have my main database on MySQL and in Flutter we have to use SQFLite to store offline data.

Anyone who can help!!!
Thank You

Comment: flutter app <-> adhara_socketio flutter package <-> node.js socket.io <-> mysql

Comment: since socket.io knows whether the socket connection is online, you can then sync your data

Comment: **Thank You** @KennethLi 
I will search for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check the solution in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54320159/8342742):

> create a DB similar to your sqflite db's table in a remote server.
> then, create a rest api using your desired language(php is easy to
> start). then, when the app is connected to internet, use HTTP client
> to send the data to the remote server.
>
> you can use a code like below for the post data call:
>
> ```
> Future<dynamic> post(String url, {Map headers, body, encoding}) {
> print(url);
> print(body);
> return http
>     .post(BASE_URL+url, body: body, headers: headers, encoding: encoding)
>     .then((http.Response response) {
>   final String res = response.body;
>   final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
>
>   print(res);
>
>   if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
>     throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
>   }
>   return _decoder.convert(res);
> });
> }
> ```